# Code from JPanel form which was made in NetBeans does not work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, jframe

I made login panel in NetBeans(you know drag and drop). I copied code to Exlipse (because there I work) and I was shocked. The code is not working properly. I see only frame and label information(even not all only one). Should code made in NetBeans work in Eclipse?

Here is my code:

```
package javaapplication40;

public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public NewJPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        LoginLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        HasloLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        MscHasla = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        MscLoginu = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        ZalogujButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        LoginLabel.setText("Login");

        HasloLabel.setText("Haslo");

        MscHasla.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                MscHaslaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        ZalogujButton.setText("Zaloguj");
        ZalogujButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ZalogujButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(ZalogujButton)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(HasloLabel)
                            .addComponent(LoginLabel))
                        .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(MscHasla)
                            .addComponent(MscLoginu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap(144, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(LoginLabel)
                    .addComponent(MscLoginu, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(HasloLabel)
                    .addComponent(MscHasla, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(ZalogujButton)
                .addContainerGap(143, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void MscHaslaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        

       private void ZalogujButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
   if( MscLoginu.getText().equals("Admin")&& MscHasla.getText().equals("1234") ){
         new GlowneOkno().setVisible(true);  

   }                                           


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel HasloLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel LoginLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField MscHasla;
    private javax.swing.JTextField MscLoginu;
    private javax.swing.JButton ZalogujButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: +1, not only this code is awesome, I LOVE how this stuff behaves.

Comment: Ok but why? what I have done?

Comment: I _would_ test it, but there's no `GlowneOkno` class.. `new GlowneOkno().setVisible(true);`

Comment: Also, it's missing a closing bracket

Comment: GlowneOkno it is just a frame without anything there it is just empty frame to see if switch between login panel and any frame will work.